# how to send a url request in opencart using CURL method?

Tags: php, html, curl, opencart

I am working in Opencart platform. now I am really stuck in integrating a sms api link. last few days I have done many things but I can't reach there. 
I don't know what is the issue in my code. I am using CURL method:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    if (substr(HTTPS_CATALOG, 0, 5) == 'https') {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $json = curl_exec($curl);

    if (!$json) {
        $this->error['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_curl'), curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));

    } else {

        curl_close($curl);
    }
}
```

this is my curl function, and I called the function like this.

```
$link= "http://**.**.**.**:****/sendsms/bulksms?username=****-****&password=********&type=0&dlr=1&destination=********&source=****&message=******"
$this->curl_get_contents($link);
```

I hope somebody will help me to survive from these problem

Comment: are you getting any errors in response?

Comment: it shows nothing, when I register a user i want send a message. but its not working.

Comment: There must be something in error_log or the system error log?

Comment: am really sorry for this post that is because of Godaddy server it will not take 8080 port. now I changed the server and working perfectly.